# Gradle alternate to mvn install

Tags: gradle

I have 2 different project build on mvn. I am trying to replace to Gradle.

Project 1 is an SDK, and project 2 is using that sdk (example).

In the time of maven it creates artifact using mvn install which adds the whole project into local repository.

I like to work in gradle like that. I like project 1 build.gradle need to post it as a gradle local repository and then example project need to use it.

In maven we do mvn install which adds a project artifact into .m2 folder  but how to do in gradle so what i can add a project artefact's into the local repository.

Any way that I can do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572811/gradle-make-a-3rd-party-jar-available-to-local-gradle-repository

Answer (score 201, accepted):

For versions of Gradle prior to 7

`sdk/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "maven"

group = "foo"
version = "1.0"
```

`example/build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile "foo:sdk:1.0"
}
```

```
$sdk> gradle install

$example> gradle build
```

Comment: apply plugin: "maven" and $sdk> gradle install   this will install the sdk into .m2 right ? 

And

mavenLocal() also gets info from .m2 and .gradle ?

Comment: `gradle install` publishes into the local Maven repo, and `mavenLocal()` makes sure to look there for dependencies.

Comment: Is Gradle not "phase-oriented" like Maven? IOW, if I do a `gradle publish` will it not also go through an `install` phase?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Do I should consider that `apply plugin: "maven"` makes available the "install" task for Gradle, right? - in some way - it is how a "transitive" (if the term fits well here) task from Maven to Gradle, right?. Consider to update your answer. Thank You

Comment: This is no long relevant in Gradle 7+ as the `maven` plugin has been removed. Instead you need to use the `maven-publish` plugin and then use `gradle publishToMavenLocal`.

Answer (score 147):

You may be looking for:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

**build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    // other plugins
    id 'maven-publish'
}


publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

See: [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Comment: It's working fine even with maven options: `gradle -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: how is this different from `gradle install` with the `maven` plugin?

Comment: @Matthew the `maven` plugin has been removed in Gradle 7

Comment: I found I had to add the publishing section, such as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58062266/7224691, to get this to work.

Comment: This also did not work for me unless I added the publishing section.

Comment: Do we really need to add `from components.java`? Why is its use exactly? I didn't add it and it is still working for me. The only thing I added is : `plugins { .. id 'maven-publish' } publishing { publications { maven(MavenPublication) { // from components.java } } }`

Answer (score 11):

Check out [Gradle's documentation on multi-project builds](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Here's an example, with some extra dependencies. Just call `gradle install` in the root folder, and all will be built and put to your local repo.

Folder structure:

```
root
+--> build.gradle
+--> settings.gradle
+--> sdk
|    +--> build.gradle
+--> example
     +--> build.gradle
```

root/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven'

  group = 'myGroup'
  version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

root/settings.gradle:

```
include 'sdk'
include 'example'
```

root/sdk/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  // just an example external dep.
  compile group:'commons-lang', name:'commons-lang', version:'2.3'
}
```

root/example/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':sdk')
  compile group:'log4j', name:'log4j', version:'1.2.16'
}
```

Comment: Is this ideal practice? What if he wants to create a new project, example2, which also relies on sdk? Now he has to put 2 unrelated projects under a root project just because they share a dependency?

You would think this entire 'multi-project' setup would be 1 Git project as well. Again, is this bad for company / multi-developer workflows?

Answer (score 10):

You need to publish your own library to your local repository. You can do that in the following way:

1. Add `maven-publish` plugin:

   ```
   plugins {
       // your other plugins come here...
       id 'maven-publish'
   }
   ```
2. Add the publishing section to your build file:

   ```
   publishing {
       publications {
           myCoolLibrary(MavenPublication) {
               from components.java
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run `gradle build publishToMavenLocal`

   Find more details in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).