# How to publish source into local maven repository with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am developing two related project. One of which is "helper" one and another is "main" one. I am constantly updating "main", but from time to time I am also updating "helper" one. After then I am running `install` goal in gradle's maven plugin and get jars in local maven repo. After that I do gradle update in "main" project and have updated jars linked.

There are two questions.

1) If staying with maven plugin, then how to publish source code into local maven repo too?

2) Can I do similar without maven plugin, staying only with Gradle?

Comment: I would use the solution that Frank Neblung linked and recommend using the -t (--coninious) option that will install it right away on every change. "gradle install -t" and as the file is changing it is not needed to reload gradle every time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's easy to publish sources with the "maven-publish" plugin:

```
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
          from components.java

          artifact sourceJar {
            classifier "sources"
          }
        }
     }
}
```

Then go publish to local maven run: `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

More info in the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: BTW, you can use abbreviated task name to reduce typing on command line, e.g. the abbreviated form of "publishToMavenLocal" is "pTML". Hence you can also run `gradle pTML`

Comment: To get this to work with Groovy/Spring project, I need to change `from sourceSets.main.allJava` to `from sourceSets.main.allSource`

Answer (score 4):

I believe a cleaner and more concise solution for this is to use the `maven-plugin`, it provides the `install` task which matches Maven's `install` task. Update your `build.gradle` to include the following:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Then to publish (e.g. install) to Maven local repository, run: `gradle install` or `./gradlew install`.
See also this solution:
[Gradle alternate to mvn install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122252/gradle-alternate-to-mvn-install)

Note: the current Gradle docs (as of v4.9) says the `maven-plugin` is the "Old Maven Plugin" (but it is not deprecated).
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

I think this is the simplest solution to this question at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are better of with a multi-module project. Then the necessity to *install* doesn't arise at all.

The topic of `-sources.jar` is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474729/how-to-build-sources-jar-with-gradle)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this by simply adding this to the build file:

```
java {    
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative skeleton for **Gradle 7.5.1** with **Java 17** which would generate `javadoc` and `sources` jars along with the source code.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.java'
    id 'org.gradle.maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'your-group'
            artifactId = 'your-artifact'
            version = "0.0.1"
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

**Publishing**

Add `--info` for more details on the publishing.

```
./gradlew --info publishToMavenLocal
```

**Output**

```
~/.m2/repository $ tree your-group/
your-group/
└── your-artifact
    ├── 0.0.1
    │   ├── your-artifact-0.0.1-javadoc.jar
    │   ├── your-artifact-0.0.1-sources.jar
    │   ├── your-artifact-0.0.1.jar
    │   ├── your-artifact-0.0.1.module
    │   └── your-artifact-0.0.1.pom
    └── maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Comment: how can I create a single package so that I can use the `implementation` function from `build.gradle`?