# Do I need the `maven` plugin if I have to use the `maven-publish` plugin too?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

This answer indicates that the `maven` plugin doesn't allow for installing source jars into the local repo. "[It's easy to publish sources with the "maven-publish" plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765267/1413900)"

With the `maven-publish` plugin, is there any reason to keep the `maven` plugin?

Comment: Why would you publish to the local repo vs `mvn install`?

Comment: @Rogue mvn install, or actually `./gradlew install` does publish to the local repo. But with the `maven` plugin, it does not publish a source jar.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Installing into the local-repo is a goal-specific task, not something you'd put in the pom. Are you wanting to block source jars in the installation repo?

Comment: @Rogue I want to install source jars in the local repo, along with, ideally, javadoc and compiled jars. I don't know why you're even mentioning the pom. There's no pom. It's gradle. Anyway, I removed the 'maven' plugin and so far so good.