# How to add a dependent project in intellij & Gradle instead using jar dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, microservices

We have multiple micro services dependent on a common code(common.jar) which is a separate project(repo).
Currently common code(common.jar) is included as dependent jar in all micro services.

```
gradle.properties:
implementation ("com.boa.dart:funding-common:23.5.1.108")  --> Prod configuration
implementation files("libs/funding-common.23.5.1.108.jar") --> Local configuration
```

As all micro services dependent on common project, development is taking much time when there is any change required in "Common Project".
First we need to do code change in "Common project", then build copy that jar to other micro services, then build each individual micro service.

But look like we can have lot of improvement in this process.

So here my question is how can I use "Common Project" in all micro services without generating common.jar.

> Here are TechStack: We are using gradle as a build tool.
> Spring Boot for micro Services.
> IntelliJ as IDE.

Comment: You can [define a composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds) that includes both your shared library and your application. This will use the classes built from the source over the one that can be downloaded from your repository.

Answer (score 2):

> So here my question is how can I use "Common Project" in all micro services without generating common.jar.

You cannot avoid having common.jar, as soon as both Maven and Gradle dependency management handles each dependency as a separate jar file.

What you can do is to create a parent `build.gradle` and include `common` module into it. In one of our projects we have the following structure:

```
root_dir/
..common/
.....src
.....build.gradle
..sql/
.....src
.....build.gradle
..api/
.....src
.....build.gradle
..build.gradle 
..settings.gradle
```

Here we created `settings.gradle` in root directory:

```
rootProject.name = 'parent'
include(':common')
include(':sql')
include(':api')
```

Under the same directory we have parent `build.gradle` with properties and settings common for all submodules:

```
allprojects {
  group = ''
  version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

ext {
  lombokVersion = '1.18.22'
  springBootVersion = '2.6.3'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  //common dependencies
  dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

    implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion")
  }

  sourceCompatibility = 17

  test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
  }
}
```

Then we have `:common` and `:sql` modules, both are dependencies for `:api` module.

In the `build.gradle` of `:api` module we juwt specify dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':sql')
  implementation project(':common')
  //...
}
```

This structure allows IDEA to import `common` project as a submodule and all changes to the code of that module will be automatically picked up and analyzed. So if you refactor or rename a property in POJO in `:common` module  IDEA finds all its usages in `:api` module and refactors/renames them as well.

Answer (score 1):

While one way is with a [multi-module gradle build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), this is not helpful when the individual microservices are split across multiple repos, each with their own repos and `build.gradle`.

In this case, there are additional options, each with their own caveats.

### mavenLocal

You can publish your `common.jar` to your maven local with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765113/how-to-publish-source-into-local-maven-repository-with-gradle).

This works well if you only have a single development machine, otherwise, each developer will have to publish to local as well.  Also, for distribution, you would have to bundle `common.jar` into the final jar, which you are likely doing already since it is included locally.

This approach would at least prevent you from having to copy/paste.

### Run a maven server

Or, of course, you could run a maven on some machine all your devices have access to.  [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository) works well.  There are others.

This requires a dedicated "server" of some kind to run this.  Might not work in all envs, but might be something worth investing in.

### Gradle Task

And, of course, as a 'low-tech' solution, if you have a common directory structure and always work out of a workspace where you have all your other repos, you can have a task in the `common`'s Gradle build that after building the jar simply copies the build artifact to the other repos based on known paths and a list of repos to update.

While potentially brittle, you could even perform git commands on those folders and prepare commits to add the changed file. YMMV on this, though, as it has plenty of its own pitfalls.

This requires all repos to be cloned, in the same relative paths, but has the advantage of simply removing the manual effort.

### Scripting

And, of course, there's no reason you have to use Gradle to do the above.  If can't use a multi-module build, and you can't use any of the other tasks, consider writing a script (bash, pwsh, python, etc), and at take advantage of some automation.

Yes, it has the pitfalls of the above, but it is simpler than doing a lot of manual tasks over and over, all of which have the potential of being skipped, forgotten, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by:

> then build copy that jar to other micro services

When you create a new version of common jar, you should have a pipeline that puts it in some artifactory/nexus from where other dependent micro services can pick up the new version automatically.

What you can also do is instruct the micro services to look for the latest, or the latest version of a major release of that common library when they build

e.g. `com.boa.dart:funding-common:23.+` will pick the latest version with the major version 23 (as long as you maintain backwards compatibility in each major version this can work).