# Building a gradle project locally for use as dependency instead of nexus?

Tags: gradle, nexus

I am working on a project which pulls in artifacts from nexus as dependencies using gradle. I am not trying to test the changes I am making in a dependency, and would like to test it. Rather than deploy it to nexus, and bump the version before I know it works, I would like to build in a way that I normally would in maven using :

```
mvn clean intall
```

Is there a way to do this with gradle? I can't find exactly what I am looking for, essentially I want to build my snapshot, and be able to import it in my project instead of pulling down the version on nexus.

I know someone is going to tell me to google this - but maybe I have been using the wrong search term - I can't find exactly what I am looking for at all with regard to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle alternate to mvn install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122252/gradle-alternate-to-mvn-install)

Comment: It might be, but there is a good answer below - se we may as well just keep it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **maven plugin**:

```
apply plugin: "maven"
```

and the use the `gradle install` task.

Otherwise you can use the **maven-publish plugin:**

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

and then the `publishToMavenLocal` task. More [info here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

These tasks build the project and then publish into the local Maven repo.

Make sure to add `mavenLocal()` to get the dependencies in your project.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```