# Maven package phase equivalent in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, maven-3, gradlew

I'm building a Spring Boot project with Gradle migrating it from Maven. I wonder what Gradle task is doing the same thing as the `package` phase in Maven.

Thank you!

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122252

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven build is based on build cycle phases, Gradle build is based on tasks and tasks dependencies.

Maven package phase can execute multiple plugin goals that is configured up to the package phase in the [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). The same thing can be achieve with gradle using tasks(and maybe creating task dependencies to integrate them in to default build)

If you only care about running unit tests and creating jar file; gradle way would be `gradle build`. If other actions are also concern in the maven package phase, additional gradle tasks should be added.

Answer (score 10):

See the diagram from the java plugin documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks)

[image: java plugin tasks]

As Matej Marconak said:

- If you want to run tests you'd run `gradle build`
- If you just want to build the jar you'd run `gradle assemble`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gradle assemble` or `gradle build`.

Comment: but assemble doesn't run tests as far as I see

Comment: ``gradle assemble`` only create .jar/.war, `gradle build` run test.

Comment: yeah, I mean something as close as possible:) ok, I guess, I'm fine with `gradle build`