# How to add built hibernate to local maven repo?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, gradle

To build hibernate (5.5) I do this:

```
git clone git://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.git
./gradlew build -x test
```

as a result I have in release/target/distributions two files:

```
hibernate-release-5.5.0-SNAPSHOT.tgz  hibernate-release-5.5.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

These files have binary and source code of the hibernate. However, built jars are not added to local maven repo. Could anyone say how to add them including sources and javadoc?

Comment: And mvn install:install-file does not help?

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122252/gradle-alternate-to-mvn-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you're looking for is `publishToMavenLocal`. And instead of `build -x test` you can use `assemble`.

```
./gradlew assemble publishToMavenLocal
```