# How to install artifacts into the local gradle filestore

Tags: maven, gradle

Can anyone tell me how to install an artifact/project into the local gradle filestore?

```
gradle install
```

installs it to the local maven repository but I need to have it in

```
~/.gradle/caches/artifacts-15/filestore
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pure cache, and you can't install into it (by design). If you could, reproducibility would suffer (build works on one machine but not on another).

Answer (score 2):

If you install it to your local maven repository and refer to the repository in you gradle build file, you will have solved your problem.

See

[Is there a way to install jar local gradle repository, as it in mave (maven install:install-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460253/is-there-a-way-to-install-jar-local-gradle-repository-as-it-in-mave-maven-inst)

EDIT: You don't even have to install the jar into your maven repo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531958/260122