# How to run build.gradle with Sikuli integrated into the project?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber, gradle, sikuli

I am using Sikuli in my project to handle some flash buttons. It's working fine while running scripts locally. The issue is that when I need to run the build.gradle, I need to have the Sikuli dependency in build.gradle. That is how I have written build.gradle. When I run the build, I get this error:

> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>
>   > Could not find com.googlecode.javacpp:javacpp:0.1.   Required by:
>   >       :new_qa_automation:1.0 > org.sikuli:sikuli-api:1.0.2 > org.sikuli:sikuli-c ore:1.0.1
>   >     Could not find com.googlecode.javacv:javacv:0.1.   Required by:
>   >       :new_qa_automation:1.0 > org.sikuli:sikuli-api:1.0.2 > org.sikuli:sikuli-c ore:1.0.1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED.

Here is my build.gradle file

> apply plugin: 'java' version = '1.0' apply plugin: 'project-report'
>
> repositories {    mavenCentral()  maven {         url
>   "http://repo.springsource.org/release"        url
>   "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"  } }
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.6 targetCompatibility = 1.6
>
> configurations {  cucumberRuntime {       extendsFrom testRuntime     } }
>
> task test(overwrite: true) { 
>       dependsOn assemble, processTestResources, compileTestJava
>       doLast {
>           javaexec {
>                         main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
>               classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
>               //some args
>
> ```
>         systemProperties System.properties
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.32.+'
>     compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'      compile
>   'org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE'
>       compile group: 'org.sikuli', name: 'sikuli-api', version: '1.0.+'     compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections',
>   version: '3.+'
>       testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.2'
>       testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.1.2'
>       testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.2'
>       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0+' 
>       }

## Edit:

I added the URL for the Maven repositry.  Now the error has changed to

> ePage.java:9: error: package org.sikuli.script does not exist 
>   import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;

Comment: Now i add url in maven repositry, error has changed as ePage.java:9: error: package org.sikuli.script does not exist
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;

Comment: FYI: you can edit your question (there's a link that says "edit" at the bottom, above the comments) to add information like this.  For the question-and-answer format of StackOverflow, it's best to edit the question with new information, rather than posting a comment on your own question.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel Waisbrot. i will do the same if i need to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sikuli-script.jar in Sikuli IDE project not provide in any repository so you must use it like a 3rd party jar

see: 
"Mavan's central repository will not answer on any Sikuli stuff" https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/185713

"Gradle: Make a 3rd party jar available to local gradle repository" [Gradle: Make a 3rd party jar available to local gradle repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572811/gradle-make-a-3rd-party-jar-available-to-local-gradle-repository)

Answer (score 0):

The Sikuli code base appears to be fragmented.  It's quite confusing; I know of 3 different sets of Java bindings.  ([one](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/), [two](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-API), [three](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html))

I think the one you're pulling with Maven is this: http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/

If so, `org.sikuli.script` is not the right import.  You don't include your code to show me what you're trying to *do* with Sikuli, but most of the things you'd want to import are somewhere under `org.sikuli.api`.

Comment: Hi , Actual in code, i am using sikuli to handle some window print buttons and also flash buttons. so i need to have sikuli in it, Locally i have sikuli-script.jar and it is working fine. but in gradle it s showing error.

Comment: basic thing is that what i need to write in build.gradle so that all the sikuli dependency gets called

Answer (score 0):

Just download the sikulix jar and mention it in build.gradle

eg: compile files('C:\Users\vedavyasa\Documents\jar\sikulixapi.jar')